# Truffle Migrate

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, ethereumj

What happens when there is a minor change in the smart contract and I run truffle migrate command.

Example:

```
//before
contract test{
    function display() public returns (string){
       return "message";
    }   
 }

//after
contract test{
    uint temp; //new var
    function display() public returns (string){
       return "updated message"; //changed message
    }   
 }
```

Ideally, it should deploy the smart contract in a different address. However, in the console, it says: Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile. Also, in ganache, I don't see a contract creation transaction. Although, in the contracts section of ganache, I can see new storage variable "temp". How is it possible if the new contract is not deployed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your contract was not deployed. To deploy your new contract you have to use `truffle migrate --reset`. Be aware that the contract is deployed at a new address and the old contract still remains on the blockchain.

To "override" your current contract (in reality it's not overriden) you have to use the Proxy Pattern.
OpenZeppelin provides a good explanation of this: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just have a question. If the contract is not deployed then how am I able to access new methods that I added? so basically when I am calling the display method "updated message" is returned.

Comment: You have to redeploy via `truffle migrate --reset`